# How to change UPDATE behavior in Spring Data JPA/Hibernate for specific field?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have to add **before UPDATE** validation for the entity field.

There is a 'status' enum field, that has 3 values(A,B,C).

So if entity has value C, it cannot be updated on A or B.

*SQL triggers are not allowed.*

I found @SQLUpdate annotation and @Where annotation, but cannot find how to use this annotations.

I tried to use @EntityListeners, but listener has entity object in argument that was already updated, but there is no access to the current value from database.

```
public class MyEntityListener {
  
@PreUpdate
  private void validateStatusFieldForUpdate(MyEntity entity) {
    if (!(entity.getStatus().equals(entity.getStatus()))
        && entity.getStatus().equals(MyEntityStatusEnum.C)) {
      throw new ListenerValidationException("Entity with status='C' cannot be updated!");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What way do you update your entity? Don't use setters, introduce the methods for making the changes and add the validation there. It will be simple and testable OOP-way

Answer (score 1):

Is a good practice to do these validations out of the persistence layer (entities & repositories)

Your case is a classic data validation that you can resolve using a validate method in static class, by example, called from any service class.

Comment: I have to read data from db to validate it. Is it ok to use repository in classic validation logic? One of solutions I have - SQL trigger.

Comment: My experience show me that use triggers is a very bad solution: these triggers depends on the database type, ypu have logic out of the application code and  database admins don't like the triggers (usually triggers are forbidden in many companies).

I ever prefer to do validations in the service layer before the repository layer.